# How to get the orientation of a edge of a marker?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have the following input image:

[image]

I need to get the orientation of the edges of the markers and draw them into the picture.
This would be the result I need:

[image]

How can I achieve this? I want to use the whole edge instead of only two corner points for calculating the line/orientation of the marker edge for higher accuracy.

Comment: Each marker has four edges. How do we know which one you're interested in?

Comment: I am interested in the lower edges of the two markers on the left hand side and I am interested in the left edges of the upper two markers

Comment: It looks like resemble to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72148782/

Comment: Have a look at the [Hough Line Transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html)